# Menú desplegable desde una imagen en el header con CSS

Tags: html, css, menu

Estoy tratando de crear una pagina principal en la cual tengo una imagen en la esquina superior derecha, en el header, y quiero que al darle clic a la imagen se despliegue un menú y al darle de nuevo clic el menú se cierre.

```
<header id="cabezal">
            <img src="IMG/logo2.png" alt="Logo de Global Finance" width="180px" id="img-izquierda">
            <img src="IMG/menu.png" alt="Imagen de tres lineas" width="32px" id="img-derecha">         
    </header>
    <section>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="Quienes_Somos.html">Quienes somos</a></li>
            <li><a href="Proyectos.html">Proyectos</a></li>
            <li><a href="Empresas.html">Empresas</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contactos.html">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
</section>
```

Se supone que el menú se despliega al darle clic a la segunda imagen, id="img-derecha".
Mi idea es hacerlo solo con CSS, pero me sirve cualquier respuesta.

Comment: No es posible con CSS. Solamente con JavaScript si querés

Comment: Si, al final lo resolví con js, muchas gracias igual.